# Referential integrity in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can we set up referential integrity between two databases in SQL Server?
If yes, how can we do this?

Comment: no, this is not possible

Answer (score 3):

From Microsoft documentation:
FOREIGN KEY constraints can reference only tables within the same database on the same server. Cross-database referential integrity must be implemented through triggers. For more information, see CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL).
Source:
[Create Foreign Key Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017)